# Is there a way to backup an SE site?

Tags: support

I am not a high rep user nor active on Meta SE yet I worried that SE might disappear forever. 
Can I backup a certain site?

Comment: There's already dumps of the databases done on a weekly cadence. I'm on mobile so I can't find the dupe target for this one.

Comment: @Makoto "dumps of the databases done on a week": where is it distributed?